# Top half of outlet is no longer "switched" and stays on contiuously!

Tags: electrical

My wall switch going to bedroom no longer turns lamps on and off and both halves of outlets have current all the time no matter what position wall switch is in.
What should I look for and do??

Comment: Check for broken switch: turn off breaker; remove switch cover plate; remove switch from box; remove one wire from switch; secure wire so end is not touching anything; turn on breaker; check switched outlet: if outlet is now dead, then switch has failed, replace it.

Comment: Did you change the outlet recently?  Still got the old one?

Answer (score 1):

If all of the wiring was properly installed previously then chances are you haven't broken the tab at the receptacle or someone else has just wired in the source and not the switch leg. Check out the drawing below:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why is the source a 3-wire cable? Black hot and red hot should be connected together at the switch box, and both connected to the black hot of a two-wire source cable. May I edit the diagram?

Comment: If a multi wire branch circuit (2 breakers) the diagram would be correct.

Comment: @Ed Beal: Yes, but would the circuit be safe? - I never wire two halves of a split outlet to two legs of a MWBC because that supplies 240V between the two hot slots. I don't want 240V potential anywhere on or in a yoke marked for 120V.

Comment: To all: The problem with a generic graphic is that it is generic. The above graphic does show two circuits connected to a single receptacle. What is obvious is that @ Don's receptacle is connected to the same circuit since the receptacle stays on no matter the position of the switch. If there were two separate circuits on opposing legs you would get a immediate phase to phase short causing a trip. In short, the graphic with @ A. I. Breveleri' s comment, the question is answered.

Comment: I wire MWBC in kitchens all the time 1 circuit on the top one on the bottom. A few years ago I quit doing this because several brands of GFCI'S were having tripping issues. @A.I.Breveleri this is 100% code compliant each outlet only has 120v with the tab broken, without the tab broken it would trip the breakers. It is the same as having 2 switches. On different circuits in a single gang box again totally legal and code compliant,

Comment: Don has not indicated what changes he may have made that triggered the failure. If he did nothing then the most likely cause is the switch has failed internally in the ON position. In that case there is no tab on the outlet and the circuit could be a MWBC without tripping the breaker.